# Equivalent of select() system call in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, select

In my script I am trying to read data from several serial ports to coordinate several devices.

I can open file descriptors to the serial ports using `exec 9</dev/ttyACM0 && exec 8</dev/ttyACM1` etc.

I was hopping I could then do something like `select()` on these file descriptors to wait on data arriving, then process it with `read 0<&9` or `read 0<&8` depending on which one had received data. Unfortunately I cannot find an equivalent of `select()` for Bash.

The closest I can find is using `read -t 0 0<&9` to poll for data to be read. I don't like this as it requires a `sleep` to prevent the script from consuming 100% the processor. Although sub second sleeps are possible e.g. `while true; do sleep 0.01; done` this consumes ~4% of the processor on my system. I can knock it back to 0.1 seconds and reduce it to <1% but it still does not "feel" the right way to do it as it adds at least 100ms of additional delay to any coordination between the devices.

Are there any solutions to this? Is there a Bash select() equivalent?

Comment: Are you saying you want something event-based instead of polling with timeouts, or that you want a less impactful way to poll?  What kind of data comes out of the serial ports?  If it's line-based, could you background a bunch of shell wrappers to `tail -F ... | while read line; do ...` that might send signals (`kill -USR1 ...`) to a central process?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do event based, but also trying to avoid a multi process scenario as that is almost the same problem. If you consider the devices as processes (all be it on a remote system) and the serial ports as pipes, it is pretty much the problem of inter process communication. I agree you could possibly do something with signals. T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting Greg's Bash Wiki http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

> There is no shell scripting equivalent to the select(2) or poll(2)
>   system calls. If you need to manage a complex suite of child processes
>   and events, don't try to do it in a shell script. (That said, there
>   are a few tricks in the advanced section http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#advanced of this page.)